# SameQ for unsorted lists

Tags: performance-tuning, sorting, expression-test

I have to compare two or more lists and check if they are the same, but their elements can be in different position. For instance

```
l1 = {a,b,c}
l2 = {b,c,a}

SameQ[l1, l2] 

(* False *)
```

but I need True.

The shortest way I can think about is

```
SameQ[Sort[l1], Sort[l2]] 

(* True *)
```

but having to compare many lists and sometimes they are really huge, I don't want to sort. Is there a built-in function or a better way to get that result?

Comment: I don't think there is a faster way (in terms of $O$). You can have some heuristics, but otherwise you won't have faster code than $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: @m0nhawk thanks for the quick reply. I agree with you that in terms of O the complexity should be that of Sort, but in terms of implementation, if there is a native function embedded in the kernel it could be faster than a couple of Sort applied to huge list. I'm not sure but it could be.

Comment: You can try to use [`Complement`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html), but I'm not sure if it would be faster (and check if it's empty).

Comment: More details on characteristics of lists might be useful - e.g., if they're symbols, strings, integers, reals, mixed, distinct elements or are duplications allowed, etc. There are very fast methods for specific use cases...

Comment: @ciao: in real cases there are only symbols into the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Complement`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html) on two lists could be used as follows:

```
Complement[l1, l2] == {}
```

> True

If you have more than one list, for example,

```
l1 = {a, b, c};
l2 = {b, c, a};
l3 = {c, b, z};
```

you could also implement it with [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) and compare the lists pairwise:

```
((Complement @@ #) == {}) & /@ Tuples[{l1, l2, l3}, 2]
```

> {True, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True}

Of course, you can also do this all in one go:

```
And @@ (((Complement @@ #) == {}) & /@ Tuples[{l1, l2, l3}, 2])
```

> False

It's not elegant, and I'm skeptical about the efficiency.

Comment: `Complement[{a, b, b}, {a, b}]` returns `{}` but the lists are not the same.

Comment: Unfortunately Complement is not always correct for my purpose (as also pointed out by ilian), and even when it is, the AbsoluteTiming registered is more or less the same of the two Sort.